# Rails: How to conditionally make a field up-dateable with a form_for tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1. I have some fields that I usually only want to show to the user (no edits) but if the user is logged in as an admin I want the fields to be editable.

But I can't get this code to work:

```
<% if current_user.admin?
simple_form_for product, :html => { :method => 'put', :multipart => true, class: 'form-vertical'}, :remote=>true do |f|
print token_tag form_authenticity_token
else
product.each do |p|
end
%>
```

Then later:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
        <%= f.input :name, :input_html => {:value => product.name} %>
        <% else %>
        <%=product.name%>
        <% end %>
```

I get  syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end

How to do this in Rails? Its a relatively straightforward procedure in the PHP world.

Comment: That error is because you don't have `end` for `simple_form_for` block.

Comment: I don't want to end my simple_form_for block because I haven't placed my input fields yet. And I only want to place input fields if the user is an admin. See the problem?

Comment: I don't think that's possible within erb.  You might be able build the string and evaluate it as view code.  But why do you need to do this? Can you not separate the content in two partials, one for `if` and other for `else`.

Comment: I *could* separate the views into two partials but then I have a bunch of duplicate code. Namely the structure of the html and my classes, etc. If I ever make a change to one I'll have to make a change to the other. That's not very DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` needs to be outside of the if condition:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <% simple_form_for product, :html => { :method => 'put', :multipart => true, class: 'form-    vertical'}, :remote=>true do |f| %>
    <% print token_tag form_authenticity_token %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
   <% product.each do |p| %>
   <% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, that's not right. Because I haven't even printed out my form fields yet and you already closed the simple_form_for statement. Later in the document I'm doing things like <%= f.input :name, :input_html => {:value => product.name} %> so how can I do that if you already closed the simple_form_for bracket?